# How to get more information about System.Xml.Xsl.XPath.XPathCompileException

Tags: c#, debugging

I have the following line of code:

```
xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));
```

`xslt is of type XslCompiledTransfrom` and `xslMarkup is a XDocument`.
Running my code I get many lines of the following message in the output window (the code runs down to the end, but still gives me this exception):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.Xsl.XPath.XPathCompileException' in System.Data.SqlXml.dll
```

So I put the code line in a try catch block

```
            try
            {xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));}
            catch (Exception e)
            {MessageBox.Show(e.Message);}
```

But during compilation it does not go into the catch block and just throws the exception into the output window.

```
1. Can anyone help me understanding the error, I just stuck here and cannot find any help?
2. Any ideas how I can get more information about the error?
```

Comment: Need to see xml file.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make the xml file public. But if the problem is with the xml file, is it possible to find out where the problem is within the file?

Comment: "But during compilation it does not go into the catch block": it never will, since `catch` is executed at runtime, not at compile time

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger? Visual Studio should pop up a window with exception details, potential inner exceptions etc.

Comment: From project menu : Add New Item, Select XML File.  Then paste XML into windows.  Error will show on the Error View just like in the other compiler errors.

Comment: to Thomas Weller: If you mean debugging mode, yes. I set breakpoints and everything. But no results. to jdweng: What do you mean by "Then past XML into windows"?